# equation spanning two columns in ieeetran

Tags: equations, ieeetran

I am writing a paper using ieee style in two columns format. Do you know how can I write an equation that spans over the two columns?

Comment: You could put it in a double column float.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See page 11 of the IEEEtran manual; there is an example at the top of the page.

> Now, the double column equations are
>   defined on the page prior to the one
>   in which they are to appear (and in
>   this example supposed that they are to
>   be equation numbers six and seven):

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
% ensure that we have normalsize text
\normalsize
% Store the current equation number.
\setcounter{MYtempeqncnt}{\value{equation}}
% Set the equation number to one less than the one
% desired for the first equation here.
% The value here will have to changed if equations
% are added or removed prior to the place these
% equations are referenced in the main text.
\setcounter{equation}{5}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_dbl_x}
x = 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + 17 + 19 + 21+ 23 + 25
+ 27 + 29 + 31
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn_dbl_y}
y = 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 + 16 + 18 + 20+ 22 + 24
+ 26 + 28 + 30
\end{equation}
% Restore the current equation number.
\setcounter{equation}{\value{MYtempeqncnt}}
% IEEE uses as a separator
\hrulefill
% The spacer can be tweaked to stop underfull vboxes.
\vspace*{4pt}
\end{figure*}
```

> The result of which is shown at the
>   top of this page. This technique
>   allows the definition of the equations
>   to be positioned arbitrarily as needed
>   so that the (floating) equations will
>   appear where desired. The “[!t]”
>   option forces LATEX to do its best to
>   place the equations at the top of the
>   next page. Had it been “[!b]” instead,
>   then the stfloats package would need
>   to be loaded and the \vspace command,
>   followed by the \hrulefill command,
>   would have to occur before the
>   equations in the figure.

Comment: Why the incantations to store and restore the "current" equation number? (Also, shouldn't there be appropriate increments added to the current equation number?)

Comment: @Willie: I quoted some more of the manual.

Comment: I've tried using the above and it does span both columns but the problem is that it does not place the long equation where I want it (following the appropriate text). How do I get it place correctly?

Comment: I tried to use this example for the same case, but the equation goes to the next page, while I use \begin{figure*}[b] instead of \begin{figure*}[!t]. How can I have the equation in the current page?

Comment: For incrementing the equation numbers smoothly that come after the two-column equations, do this % Restore the current equation number. \setcounter{MYtempeqncnt}{\value{equation}} \setcounter{equation}{\value{MYtempeqncnt}} instead of just, % Restore the current equation number. \setcounter{equation}{\value{MYtempeqncnt}} Doing this will assign the current equation number to the counter first and then use the counter for the equations that follow.

Comment: Why are you using `\setcounter{MYtempeqncnt}{\value{equation}}` ? can we use it without it?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I could find to have wide equations in ieee style is the following:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\onecolumn  % add this line after \begin{document} but before \titlepage
\begin{multicols}{2}  %Before starting of \begin{abstract}
\end{multicols}  % before the \begin{equation}
\begin{equation}
 %enter wide or long equation here
\end{equation}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\end{multicols} %just before \end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! For hours I was struggling with \strip and it made some parts of the text invisible. But this works like a charm :)