# Strip environment (for widetext) eating subsequent text (and leaving a 9 when in twocolumn)

Tags: memoir, cuted

I've been trying to use the *strip* environment (called via *widetext*) to insert full-width text selectively when in *twocolumn* mode.  When using it only once per page, it seems to work just fine.  Used more than that, it results in entire sections of subsequent text vanishing, being replaced by the number 9.  (When not in *twocolumn*, there's no 9, but even more sections vanish.)

(Note: I don't have sufficient "reputation" to use the keyword tags useful to my post.)

```
\documentclass[
    twocolumn,
    ]{memoir}
\usepackage{cuted}
%   \usepackage{etoolbox}
%   \AfterEndEnvironment{strip}{\leavevmode} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264510/unexpected-behavior-of-cuted-strip

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}

    \section{Section 1}

    Text 1

\end{strip}

\section{Section 2}

Text 2

\begin{strip}

    \section{Section 3}

    Text 3

\end{strip}

\subsection{Section 4}

Text 4

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest to contact the maintainer  Sigitas Tolušis sigitas@vtex.lt

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer) I cannot confirm any disappearing acts of sections or subsections using `cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes`.

**UPDATE** I can now confirm that the issue can be reproduced using the last update of `cuted`:   `cuted.sty    2021/10/04 v2.0 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes`. See the last figure.

[image: a]

[image: b]

**The disappearing act**

[image: d]

Try this code. (just added a dummy text to check the wide behavior)

Compiled with

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.10.12)`

and

`memoir.cls  2021/03/23 v3.7o configurable book, report, article document class`

and also

`memoir.cls    2021/06/16 v3.7p configurable book, report, article document class`

`cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes`

```
\documentclass[
twocolumn,
]{memoir}

\usepackage{cuted}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text


%   \usepackage{etoolbox}
%   \AfterEndEnvironment{strip}{\leavevmode} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264510/unexpected-behavior-of-cuted-strip

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
0. \kant[9]

\begin{strip}

    \section{Section 1}
    
    1. \kant[1]

\end{strip}

\section{Section 2}

2. \kant[2]

\begin{strip}

    \section{Section 3}
    
    3. \kant[3]

\end{strip}

\subsection{Subsection 4}

4. \kant[4]

\begin{strip}
    
    \section{Section 5}
    
    5. \kant[9]
    
\end{strip}

6. \kant[6]
    
\end{document}
```

Output in the `.log` file by adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{`

```
*File List*
 memoir.cls    2021/06/16 v3.7p configurable book, report, article document class
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
   mem10.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 10pt size option
   array.sty    2021/04/20 v2.5e Tabular extension package (FMi)
 dcolumn.sty    2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
delarray.sty    2014/10/28 v1.01 array delimiter package (DPC)
tabularx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
textcase.sty    2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
mparhack.sty    2005/04/17 v1.4 (T. Sgouros and S. Ulrich)
   cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
kantlipsum.sty    2019/07/23 v0.8 Generate text in Kantian style
   expl3.sty    2021-02-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xparse.sty    2021-01-09 L3 Experimental document command parser
xparse-2020-10-01.sty    
 ***********
```

Comment: with a texlive updated yesterday the whole of section 2 goes and there is a 9 in place if I run your code `Document Class: memoir 2021/06/16 v3.7p`

Comment: @David Carlisle I get the same (good) result using `memoir.cls    2021/06/16 v3.7p `

Comment: can you add `\listfiles` and add the list to your answer?

Comment: @David Carlisle   `cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 `

Comment: Package: cuted 2021/10/04 v2.0 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the version of cuted.sty(default V2.0). Just use the older version V1.5 and the  missing context will appear.

Here is the link of the cuted.sty(V1.5):
https://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2017/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty?view=log

download the 2017 years version and replace V2.0 with it in your own computer files(e.g. D:\latex\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\sttools)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The OP said using v1.5 is not an answer.

Comment: The existing answer already mentions, that `cuted` v1.5 is working.

Comment: Thanks for remind, my reputation is not enough to write the comment. So I have to choose write the answer. En, just to give some linkes and operations to get v1.5.