# formula width in double column paper

Tags: alignment, formulas

I have a formula which has a content like below..

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[c]
reward(node, action)  = \begin{cases}
    constant\_action\_reward -\par action\_cost +
    success\_prob(action, sequence) * node\_reward,& \text{if } "XXX"=action
    constant\_action\_taking\_reward - action\_cost, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I tried this both in double column using the * like {equation*} and not. Paper is double column. In each option, this covers a two column and other text comes over this. I attached a sample picture. I would be happy if it fits a single column or at least it covers a double column and no text comes over it.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: For sure, you should tell us which document class you employ, which font families are used (unless they're the document class' default), and which main font size you use.

Comment: What's the purpose of using an `aligned` environment?

Comment: unrelated but use `\mathrm{constant\_action\_reward}` (or `\mathit`) never use the math italic font for multi-letter words, it makes adjacent letters look like a product of 1-letter variables

Comment: For `ieeetran`, its [user manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en) describes how to do double-column equations (it is a bit unwieldy) by using floats on or around page 12. See also [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/equation-spanning-two-columns-in-ieeetran). // Incidentally, the code you showed is also missing a line break after `"xxx"=action`.  And I an not sure what `\par` is doing in the middle of the equation. The code you provided as stands cannot be compiled.

Comment: Your equation is longer than `\textwidth`. Even if you write across both columns, it will not fit on the page.  To my opinion the best is rephrase this part of your article and avoid to use equation.

Comment: However, you can try to write long terms in several lines, for example as `   = \begin{cases}
        \begin{aligned}
        & \mathit{constant\_action\_reward} - \\[-1ex]
        & \mathit{action\_cost} + \mathit{success\_prob(action, sequence)}* \\[-1ex] 
        & \mathit{node\_reward}
        \end{aligned}`. But even with this trick equation is to long.  So the next try is to define abbreviations for your text in equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use a Times compatible font also for math and also wrap your long names in `\mathit` or similar.

Second, you need to split the long top line. Using `cases` is out of the question, I'm afraid.

A bit of visual formatting helps.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtx} % for math symbol compatible with Times

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\tv}[1]{\mathit{#1}} % text variable

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\hspace{-0.5em}
\begin{aligned}
&\tv{reward}(\tv{node}, \tv{action}) \\
& =
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\begin{aligned}
      \begin{aligned}
        &\tv{constant\_action\_reward} - \tv{action\_cost} \\
        &+ \tv{success\_prob}(\tv{action}, \tv{sequence}) \cdot \tv{node\_reward},
      \end{aligned}
      \\
      \text{if } \text{"XXX"}=\tv{action}\hspace{-0.3em}
    \end{aligned}
  \\[2ex]
    &\begin{aligned}
      \tv{constant\_action\_taking\_reward} - \tv{action\_cost},
      \\
      \text{otherwise}\hspace{-1em}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{aligned}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [Zarko commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652184/formula-width-in-double-column-paper#comment1625459_652184) your equation wouldn't fit even if you use double-column.

The first option, which I think is the best, is to use shorter variable names.

If you must use the formula exactly as it appears, [Zarko suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652184/formula-width-in-double-column-paper#comment1625460_652184) you break the first line of the `cases`. I think it looks better instead of you break before the `cases`. (And you should display this with the full text width: in one column using the variable names as they stand there is no way to display your equation in fewer than 5 lines, which makes it not very legible.)

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\lipsum


\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\normalsize
\begin{multline}
    \mathsf{reward(node, action)}  = \\
    \begin{cases}
        \mathsf{constant\_action\_reward} - \mathsf{action\_cost} +
        \mathsf{success\_prob(action, sequence)} * \mathsf{node\_reward},& \text{if ``XXX''=action}  \\
        \mathsf{constant\_action\_taking\_reward} - \mathsf{action\_cost}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{multline}
\hrulefill
% The spacer can be tweaked to stop underfull vboxes.
\vspace*{4pt}
\end{figure*}

\begin{equation}
    E = mc^e
\end{equation}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

1. I wrapped your variable names in `\mathsf` since they look like computer variable names. If they were words I would use `\mathrm` or `\mathit` as David Carlisle suggested.
2. There are some other small mistakes in the displayed equation that I fixed.
3. I have no idea what the semantic meaning of `"XXX"=action` is, so I left them as text. But you should adjust to fit the meaning.
4. If you compile this document, you will see that the the equation is numbered out of order. This is "by design": the IEEEtran documentation indicates a preference for double-column equations to be floated to the top of the next page. The code included in the documentation provides a way to restore the correct numbering; but this requires manual intervention and should be set AFTER you finished your entire document. So I omit that in the code above.