# Long equations break with split or multlined

Tags: math-mode, equations, split, multline

I am using the IEEEtran class (two columns) for a paper, and have several long expressions that I cannot figure out the best way to format them. I am currently using `\split` and aligning everything manually as I see best for clarity, but this takes up a lot of space. Perhaps with the use of `\multlined` and `\shoveright` I can get better results.
Below is the MWE:

```
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \mathcal{UB}\left(\underset{\boldsymbol{Z}}{\mathrm{E}}\log C_{pq}\right)
        &=-\frac{\log p}{p}-\frac{\log q}{q}\\
        &\phantom{=}-\mathcal{E}_B\log m_{Z}-\log m_{X}\\
        &\phantom{=}+ \mathcal{E}_B\log\left(m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}+m_{Z}M_{Z}^{p-1}\right)\\
        &\phantom{=}+\Pr{(B)}\log\Biggl( m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}\\
        &\phantom{=+\Pr{(B)}\log\Biggl(}
        +\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z}\left(\sup_{Z\in B}M_Z\right)^{p-1}\Biggr)\\
        &\phantom{=}-\Pr{(B)}\log\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z},
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered]

If using `\multlined` then the MWE would be:

```
\begin{align}
        \begin{multlined}
            \mathcal{UB}\left(\underset{\boldsymbol{Z}}{\mathrm{E}}\log C_{pq}\right)
            =-\frac{\log p}{p}-\frac{\log q}{q}\\
            -\mathcal{E}_B\log m_{Z}-\log m_{X}\\
            + \mathcal{E}_B\log\left(m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}+m_{Z}M_{Z}^{p-1}\right)\\
            +\Pr{(B)}\log\Biggl( m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}\\
            +\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z}\left(\sup_{Z\in B}M_Z\right)^{p-1}\Biggr)\\
            -\Pr{(B)}\log\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z},
        \end{multlined}
    \end{align}
```

[image: render]

In my full document, as the IEEEtran is two column, the equations often overflow a bit into the other column. What would be the best way to handle these scenarios?

Comment: You can surely use two columns for such a long equation. This question might be a duplicate (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/equation-spanning-two-columns-in-ieeetran).

Answer (score 1):

### First proposal

The math fonts clearly clash with the text font.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{E}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  &\mathcal{UB}\bigl(\,\E_{\boldsymbol{Z}}\log C_{pq}\bigr) \\
  &\quad=-\frac{\log p}{p}-\frac{\log q}{q}-\mathcal{E}_B\log m_{Z}-\log m_{X}\\
  &\qquad+ \mathcal{E}_B\log(m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}+m_{Z}M_{Z}^{p-1})\\[1ex]
  &\qquad\begin{aligned}[t]
    &+\Pr(B)\log\bigl( m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}\\
    &\qquad+\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z}\bigl(\sup_{Z\in B}M_Z\bigr)^{p-1}\bigr)
    \end{aligned} \\[1ex]
  &\qquad-\Pr(B)\log\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second proposal

Matching math and text fonts.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{E}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  &\mathcal{UB}\bigl(\,\E_{\bm{Z}}\log C_{pq}\bigr) \\
  &\quad=-\frac{\log p}{p}-\frac{\log q}{q}-\mathcal{E}_B\log m_{Z}-\log m_{X}\\
  &\qquad+ \mathcal{E}_B\log(m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}+m_{Z}M_{Z}^{p-1})\\[1ex]
  &\qquad+\Pr(B)\log\bigl( m_{X}M_{X}^{q-1}
         +\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z}\bigl(\sup_{Z\in B}M_Z\bigr)^{p-1}\bigr) \\[1ex]
  &\qquad-\Pr(B)\log\inf_{Z\in B}m_{Z},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Comments

I don't think there's a gain in clarity with big fences. Actually, I believe the contrary.

The command `\Pr` doesn't take an argument. Look closely at the difference between `\Pr(B)` and `\Pr{(B)}` and you'll see that the latter is wrong.